# Perl: closing subprocess pipe in signal handler hangs?

Tags: linux, perl, pipe, signals, alarm

I need to timeout on a script that's doing blocking io.
Surprisingly it turns out `exit` hangs if there is an open pipe to a subprocess:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                                             
(-f "foo") || die "file foo doesn't exist";
open(IN, "tail -f foo |");

$SIG{ALRM} = sub
{
    print "trying to exit...\n";
    exit 0;     # Hangs with above open() call
};
alarm 1;

while (1)
{   
    sleep 5;   # Do stuff ...
}
```

With no `open` call it works, unfortunately removing it is not an option in this case the script needs it.

Looks like `exit` is trying to close the filehandle and this is what is hanging:

```
$SIG{ALRM} = sub
{
    print "trying to close...\n";
    close(IN);            # Hangs ...
    print "ok\n";
    exit 0;
};
```

I guess it's not too happy about reaping the child from inside a signal handler...

Does anyone know a good way around this ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The signal handler is a red herring, [close](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/close.html) will block regardless:

```
open my $foo, "tail -f foo |" or die "Can't open process: $!";

close $foo;     # <--- will block
```

One way to fix this is to capture the sub process id via [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) and then [kill](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/kill.html) that child:

```
my $subprocess = open my $foo, "tail -f foo |" or die "Can't open process: $!";

say "subprocess=$subprocess";

kill 'KILL', $subprocess;

close $foo;     # <--- happy now
```

Comment: Of course you're quite right, silly me ! The confusing part was that an early `exit` actually works but only because it creates a race condition (the child isn't ready yet). Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Using `POSIX::_exit()` directly like the man page suggests seems to work around this particular issue. But this smells of an A-B problem. Are you sure that your real problem is not better solved by using a more sophisticated way of handling subprocesses than plain pipes, like for example `IPC::Run`?